# Filenames that are given on the command line

Tags: php

I want to read the file name from command line rather than using `file_get_contents("filename.txt");` 
command.

I want to read the file from command line and place the output file in the same place(command line) in the form of `php myprog.php 1 input.txt output.txt`
where `input.txt` is the input file and `output.txt` is the output file.

which function can I use in this place?

Need some help.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$argv` - it is an array of all the arguments passed to the script when running from the command line. You can then iterate through it and do whatever you need to do based on the count, value of the array keys..

```
<?php
   var_dump($argv);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Command-line options passed to the PHP script (which itself is passed to the PHP interpreter as a command line argument, so it's just packaging the arguments up for the script to use) are found [in the `$argv` array](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php).